# What is the battery life of Lenovo t431s with Ubuntu?

Tags: battery, lenovo

I realize that some of you may own a Lenovo t431s laptop. Could you please share, what is a realistic battery life that I could expect from it with web/WiFi/coding usage?
I couldn't find any Linux benchmarks anywhere from the Internet yet.

Thank you!

Comment: It should be close to Windows's usage. If you're lucky, it could even be better on Ubuntu than on Windows.

Comment: Have a look http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about specs of some specific hardware rather than Ubuntu.

Comment: Practice shows that it rarely close to Windows usage. I know how to tweak power consumption in Linux, I am more interested in real situation.

I don't think that this question is off as it's about running Ubuntu on specific hardware, so it's about Ubuntu in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

My T431s on Ubuntu 13.04 usually lasts about 5-6 hours under normal load. (Wifi up, full brightness, doing actual work.)

Answer (score 0):

The Lenovo website says up to 9 hours of battery life, and this is based on Windows 7. If you are using it for browsing the web and coding, you should expect 7-8 hours, maybe a little less. This is because Ubuntu uses more power than Windows. The drivers on the computer are designed to work with Windows, and so when you use Ubuntu, not all of them are used and this takes up power. If you are concerned with battery life, take a look at some power saving tweaks [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks).

A tool I have used to improve Ubuntu's battery life is Jupiter. I find that it is really nice because it changes some parameters and settings on your computer based on whether your computer is on battery power or is connected to a power source.

To install it, open up Terminal in Ubuntu (Dash -> Search for Terminal) and use the following code:

```
    sudo add-apt repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

You can also try powertop. This helps with debugging what processes eat up your power. Read more about it [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/powertop).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: I apologize, Jupiter is not compatible with the latest kernel. Thank you Qasim.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately official data has not to do with attempt to correlate real battery life. Different reviews says that realistic BF is around 5-6 ours in Windows. When I had Lenovo X1 - it's battery life (with all possible tweaks) was 2 times worse than Windows one. So I am interested in real experience with this laptop if anybody has one..